# What is the use-case for TryEnterCriticalSection?

Tags: winapi, critical-section

I've been using Windows `CRITICAL_SECTION` since the 1990s and I've been aware of the `TryEnterCriticalSection` function since it first appeared.  I understand that it's supposed to help me avoid a context switch and all that.

But it just occurred to me that I have never used it.   Not once. 
 Nor have I ever felt I needed to use it.  In fact, I can't think of a situation in which I would.

Generally when I need to get an exclusive lock on something, I need that lock and I need it now.  I can't put it off until later. I certainly can't just say, "oh well, I won't update that data after all".  So I need `EnterCriticalSection`, not `TryEnterCriticalSection`

So what exactly is the use case for `TryEnterCriticalSection`?

I've Googled this, of course.   I've found plenty of quick descriptions on ***how*** to use it but almost no real-world examples of ***why***.   I did find this example [from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/use-non-blocking-locks-when-possible) that, frankly doesn't help much:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

    void threadfoo()
    {
        while(TryEnterCriticalSection(&cs) == FALSE)
        {
             // some useful work
        }

        // Critical Section of Code

        LeaveCriticalSection (&cs);
    }

    // other work
}
```

What exactly is a scenario in which I can do "some useful work" while I'm waiting for my lock?  I'd love to avoid thread-contention but in my code, by the time I need the critical section, I've already been forced to do all that "useful work" in order to get the values that I'm updating in shared data (for which I need the critical section in the first place).

Does anyone have a real-world example?

Comment: The difference is that [`TryEnterCriticalSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-tryentercriticalsection) returns immediately, regardless of whether it obtained ownership of the critical section, while `EnterCriticalSection` blocks until the thread can take ownership of the critical section. If you want it to spin, you can write your own `Try­Enter­Critical­Section`. Refer to [@Raymond's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100426-00/?p=14243).

Comment: Hi Rita,  Appreciate the reply but that wasn't really my question.  I do understand the differences between the two, I was just looking for real-world examples of when people need to use it.   The answer by "500 - Internal Server Error" seems to come closest to that but mostly what I'm taking away from this  -- both in this question and in general googling on the topic -- is that people don't really use this function much, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

As an example you might have multiple threads that each produce a high volume of messages (events of some sort) that all need to go on a shared queue.

Since there's going to be frequent contention on the lock on the shared queue, each thread can have a local queue and then, whenever the `TryEnterCriticalSection` call succeeds for the current thread, it copies everything it has in its local queue to the shared one and releases the CS again.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 there`std::lock` which employs deadlock-avoidance algorithm.

In C++17 this has been elaborated to `std::scoped_lock` class.

This algorithm tries to lock on mutexes in one order, and then in another, until succeeds. It takes `try_lock` to implement this approach.

Having `try_lock` method in C++ is called `Lockable` named requirement, whereas mutexes with only `lock` and `unlock` are `BasicLockable`.

So if you build C++ mutex on top of `CTRITICAL_SECTION`, and you want to implement `Lockable`, or you'll want to implement lock avoidance directly on `CRITICAL_SECTION`, you'll need `TryEnterCriticalSection`

---

Additionally you can implement timed mutex on `TryEnterCriticalSection`. You can do few iterations of `TryEnterCriticalSection`, then call `Sleep` with increasing delay time, until `TryEnterCriticalSection` succeeds or deadline has expired. It is not a very good idea though. Really timed mutexes based on user-space WIndows synchronization objects are implemented on `SleepConditionVariableSRW`, `SleepConditionVariableCS` or `WaitOnAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Because windows CS are recursive TryEnterCriticalSection  allows a thread to check whether it already owns a CS without risk of stalling.

Another case would be if you have a thread that occasionally needs to perform some locked work but usually does something else, you could use TryEnterCriticalSection and only perform the locked work if you actually got the lock.

Comment: Appreciate the reply.  I guess I was looking for  some real-world examples of people occasionally having only to occasionally perform some locked work and it being OK if it cannot be locked and performed.   Because in my experience I have not encountered many (perhaps any) such situations.  But I wonder if that might be  because I haven't always taken the best approach to design.  So I'm hoping people who have used this API could set me straight